# Explanation/ Intuition for part of Trace Proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Given that $A \in R^{n \times m}$ and $B \in R^{m \times n}$

The following holds true about their traces.

\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{tr}(AB) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (AB)_{ii}\\
    &=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ji}\\
    &= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n B_{ji}A_{ij}\\
    &= \sum_{j=1}^m (BA)_{jj}\\
    &= \mathrm{tr}(BA)
\end{align*}

Can someone explain / provide intuition why $\sum_{i=1}^n (AB)_{ii}$ splits into $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ji}$?

Maybe an example matrix would help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of matrix multiplication, the $i,k$ entry of $AB$ is given by
$$
(AB)_{ik}  = \sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij} B_{jk}.
$$
Thus, taking $k = i$ in the above, we can write
$$
\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{tr}(AB) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (AB)_{ii}
    =\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ji}\right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ji}. \\
\end{align*}
$$

---

As for an example: I recommend that you look at this in detail the case that $m = 1$ and $n$ is any value ($n = 3$ for instance).